# JSF commandLink not working after migration to primefaces 5

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to upgrade my application to primefaces-5.0, primefaces extensions 2.0.0 and javax.faces-2.1.27 versions. I got following error after clicking on image which before in application was working fine.

> SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error. 
>   jsf.js.xhtml, line 1 character 33114(error is at below line c.submit();)
>
> mojarra.jsfcljs=function jsfcljs(c,b,a){mojarra.apf(c,b);var d=c.target;if(a){c.target=a}**c.submit()**;c.target=d;mojarra.dpf(c)};

Code:

```
<h:panelGroup style="float:right;">

<h:commandLink id="pdfDataExporterLink" action="#{bean.createPDF}" >
   <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.exportFileName}" value="pdfFilename.pdf" />
   <h:graphicImage  id="searchPdf" styleClass="rollover" style="border:none;" library="images" name="pdf.png"></h:graphicImage>
   <p:tooltip for="searchPdf" value="Export to PDF" />         
</h:commandLink>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Rendered code

```
<a id="formId:pdfDataExporterLink" href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('formId'),
{'formId:pdfDataExporterLink':'formId:pdfDataExporterLink'},'');return false"><img id="formId:searchPdf" src="/javax.faces.resource/pdf.png.xhtml?ln=images" style="border:none;" 
class="rollover" />
```

Comment: Is there a `form` encapsulating that code?

Comment: yes form id is formId